# Tensor product of free modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, projective-module, free-modules

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are free $R$-module($R$ is a commutative ring). The tensor product of $M\otimes_R N$ is free $R$-module?  I know for projective modules it is true. How should we build its basis?

Comment: A basis is the most natural possible: the tensor product of bases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$[\bigoplus\limits_{i} R] \otimes_R [ \bigoplus\limits_j R] \cong \bigoplus\limits_{i,j} R \otimes_R R \cong \bigoplus\limits_{i,j} R$$

Comment: That's right. And what about basis?

Comment: If you go through those isomorphisms explicitly, you should be able to see what the basis is